# JUnit: what am I missing

Tags: java, recursion, junit, tostring

Can someone tell me how does JUnit operate and how can I fix this code? I am sure there is a bunch of error that I am unable to find.

Method Code:

```
   public static String findMinimumRecursive(String[] array, String 
currentMinString){// another bonus method
        if(array.length == 0)
            return currentMinString;
            return findMinimumRecursive(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, 
array.length), 
((Integer)currentMinString.length()).compareTo(array[0].length()) < 0 ?  
currentMinString : array[0]); 

  }
```

toString Code:

```
public String toString()
{
    String result;
   result = " result : " + (findMinimumRecursive(stringArray));
   return recursiveCompare;
}
```

JUnit code:

```
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class recursiveCompareTester{

    private String [] tringArray = new String[4];

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        stringArray[4] = {"delta","alpha","omega","zeta"}
    }

    @Test
    public void recursiveCompareTester() {
        assertEquals(findMinimumRecursive(stringArray).toString,zeta );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `toString` method here which is not needed. Remove the `toString` method first. Then the class being tested should look like this.

```
public class RecursiveCompare {
    public static String findMinimumRecursive(String[] array, String currentMinString) {// another bonus method
        if (array.length == 0)
            return currentMinString;
        return findMinimumRecursive(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length),
                ((Integer) currentMinString.length()).compareTo(array[0].length()) < 0 ? currentMinString : array[0]);

    }
}
```

I have seen some issues in declaring array in your test class and I have fixed them too. Here's the correct version of the test class.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RecursiveCompareTester {
    private String[] stringArray;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        stringArray = new String[] { "delta", "alpha", "omega", "zeta" };
    }

    @Test
    public void recursiveCompareTester() {
        assertEquals(RecursiveCompare.findMinimumRecursive(stringArray, "invalid"), "zeta");
    }
}
```

This test merely passes.

Comment: I tried it and I got an error : recursiveCompareTester.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        assertEquals(findMinimumRecursive(stringArray, "invalid"), "zeta");
                     ^
  symbol:   method findMinimumRecursive(String[],String)
  location: class recursiveCompareTester
1 error    Any idea?

Comment: Just add a static import like so `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;`

Comment: I have updated my answer with the `import` statements in the test class. Does it work now?

Comment: I have used it with the import when I tried. it still does work.  recursiveCompareTester.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        assertEquals(RecursiveCompare.findMinimumRecursive(stringArray, "invalid"), "zeta");
                     ^
  symbol:   variable RecursiveCompare
  location: class recursiveCompareTester
1 error

Comment: it worked now it was because of Capitalization on RecursiveCompare lol

Comment: I don't understand what the "invalid" part is for

Comment: Ok your method takes 2 params, one is the array and other is the string. So I just passed that as the argument to the 2nd param which is named `currentMinString`

Comment: Please either accept it as the answer, up or down vote it depending on how helpful it was to solve the problem you stated. That's the practice we follow here, just FYI.